# How can I capture multiple matches from the same Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, string

I'm trying to parse a single string and get multiple chunks of data out from the same string with the same regex conditions. I'm parsing a single HTML doc that is static (For an undisclosed reason, I can't use an HTML parser to do the job.) I have an expression that looks like:

```
$string =~ /\<img\ssrc\="(.*)"/;
```

and I want to get the value of $1. However, in the one string, there are many img tags like this, so I need something like an array returned (@1?) is this possible?

Comment: In these cases, I add more context to my regex to get to the particular image tag I want. That is, when I don't feel like doing it right by using an HTML parser, like HTML::SimpleLinkExtor which extracts all the img src values for you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As Jim's answer, use the /g modifier (in list context or in a loop).

But beware of greediness, you dont want the `.*` to match more than necessary (and dont escape < = , they are not special).

```
while($string =~ /<img\s+src="(.*?)"/g ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, yeah I was having a problem with the greediness, that ? fixed it. Say, would you happen to know the list of characters that need to be escaped in regex? I basically escape almost everything because I don't know better :P

Comment: In general you must escape metacharacters and quantifiers. In Perl you have: `Metacharacters: . $ ^ | () [] \  Quantifiers: * + ? {}`
But there are some complications - in particular, inside a character class [] things change.

Comment: ...but the better way to fix that greediness problem is to use `"([^"]*)"`. In many regex engines, this will be more effcient, but, more importantly, it is a clearer statement of your intent: You want to match " followed by some number of *non-doublequote* characters, followed by another ", not two " characters separated by the shortest possible sequence of *any characters at all*.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, those are the two common ways of specifying non-greediness, and it's good to be aware of both and use the more appropiate. But (though I agree that yours is a little more semantically correct), in this particular pattern (which ends at the quote) they are exactly equivalent (functionally, perhaps not speedwise) and mine was a little more clear at the eyes.

Comment: Definitely not speedwise. Backtracking will force /".*?"/ to rescan the string every time it fails to satisfy the secondary double-quote. For instance, against "abcd", it must first try ", then "a, then "ab, and so on and so forth until it finds that second quote. While a smart regex compiler might be able to optimize this (continue scanning until you reach "), I would not rely on a compiler being that smart. In general, avoid .* unless you really, truly mean it.

Answer (score 14):

```
@list = ($string =~ m/\<img\ssrc\="(.*)"/g);
```

The **g** modifier matches all occurences in the string. List context returns all of the matches. See the **m//** operator in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

Answer (score 6):

You just need the global modifier /g at the end of the match. Then loop through
until there are no matches remaining

```
my @matches;
while ($string =~ /\<img\ssrc\="(.*)"/g) {
        push(@matches, $1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the /g modifier and list context on the left, as in

```
@result = $string =~ /\<img\ssrc\="(.*)"/g;
```

Comment: But I don't have an array of strings, just one. I'm trying to get individual sources out of the multiple img tags in the single string, returned as an array. I tried this but it didn't return anything.

Comment: What do you think that binding operator is doing? :)

Comment: I omitted part of the answer by accident.  It has been corrected.