# Regular Expression between 2 strings (Numeric Only )

Tags: regex

I have this code that I need to do a regular expression between "media_count": and ,. 
Meaning I should end up only with  370606 , 168, 250 , 67

```
{"position": 0, "hash": {"media_count": 370606, "name": "fsdfs", "id": 17843681947041535}}, {"position": 34, "hash": {"name": "fsdfsd", "media_count": 168, "id": 17842650601031598}}, {"hashtag": {"name": "fsdfsd", "media_count": 250, "id": 17843868538053719}, "position": 17},  {"position": 7, "hashtag": {"name": "dgdfg", "id": 17854319125027806, "media_count": 67}},
```

any whll will be apreciated

Comment: Try `"media_count":\s*(\d+)\s*,`

Comment: I do not see a reason against a good `json` parser.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you didn't mention a language, so i'll give you a perl answer.
you can see a question regarding multiple matches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884549/how-can-i-capture-multiple-matches-from-the-same-perl-regex).
Second, for perl, your regexp will look like this:
`@mc = $your_string =~ /\"media_count\"\:\s*(\d+)/g`
my try:
`test > perl -p -e '@list = $_ =~ /\"media_count\":\s*(\d+)/g; print "@list \n" ' somefile
370606 168 250 67`

Answer (score 0):

```
"media_count":(?<=)\s*(\d+)\s*
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/0dZUMT/1)

group 1 will contain the numbers what you are looking for

or only full matches for numbers after "media_count":

```
(?<="media_count":\s)\d+\s*
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help after seen your code it just made sense.. I end up using (?<="media_count": )\s*(\d+)\s*

Comment: if your aim is only full match, without groups, you can try `(?<="media_count":\s)\d+\s*`